# How to develop and compile Java SWT application that runs on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, raspberry-pi, swt

What is the best method to develop a Java SWT application on a Windows 64Bit OS with eclipse which runs on a Raspberry Pi 32Bit?

My problem is, that I cannot run my compiled applications by `java -jar app.jar`, caused by wrong bundled swt.jar:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
        no swt-win32-4629 in java.library.path
        no swt-win32 in java.library.path
        Can't load library: /home/user/.swt/lib/linux/arm/libswt-win32-4629.so
        Can't load library: /home/user/.swt/lib/linux/arm/libswt-win32.so`
```

When I use the swt.jar for Raspberry Pi, I cannot run it on Windows and vice versa.
What is the best way to develop and run it with only one build? Which libraries do I need to install? Should the swt.jar be packaged in the executable .jar?

Answer (score 0):

On your windows machine - you need an emulator for the Rasberry PI.  There are good discussions about it on the [rasberry stack exchange site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/344/emulation-on-a-windows-pc).